# Is there a way to configure anonymous function signature line break settings in Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

I'd like my anonymous functions as parameters to be formatted like this:

```cs
var promise = new Promise().Then(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
});
```

However Resharper always formats them like so:

```cs
var promise = new Promise().Then(
    () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    });
```

Is there any way to configure this to look like the former example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have an option "Prefer wrap "(" after invocation" turned on. Please try to turn it off.

It can be found under Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line Breaks and Wrapping > Arrangement of invocations

[image: ReSharper Options Screenshot]

Unfortunately, currently there is no possibility to separate cases where parameter is lambda from other cases, but we have that in plans.

To discover settings affecting your piece of code yourself you can use "Detect formatting settings" or "Configure formatting" features. Select a code with desired formatting, Alt-Enter > Format selection > Configure... or Detect formatting settings...

Comment: Does this answer still hold now, ~2.5 years later?  It would be nice to get the lambda args on the same line as the invocation if it's the only param (this is also Prettier default behavior).

Comment: Dimitry, is there a YouTrack issue we can follow for "separate cases where parameter is lambda from other cases, but we have that in plans"?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-467905 @ZizhengTai